# Swift - saveContext(), tableView, scrollView, and reloadRows issue?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have tableView that uses a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate data. When clicking on a cell, it takes you to a detailViewController of that object. And the following two properties are pushed forward with prepare(for:).

```
var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack!
var selectedGlaze: Glaze?
```

Inside the detailView, I have 2 cells. The first is cell that contains a scrollView with an array of images:

```
import UIKit

protocol SwipedRecipeImageViewDelegate: class {
    func recipeImageViewSwiped(_ cell: RecipePhotoTableViewCell, selectInt: Int)
}

class RecipePhotoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    // -
    
    var imagesArray: [Data] = []
    var selectedImageData: Int = 0
    
    // -
    weak var delegate: SwipedRecipeImageViewDelegate?
    // -
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false // Allows didSelectAtRow:
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer) // Allows Scrolling
    }
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setImages()
        setOffsetX(pageNumber: selectedImageData)
    }
    
    
    func configureCell(section: Int, row: Int, images: [RecipeImage], arrayInt: Int, delegate: SwipedRecipeImageViewDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        
        selectedImageData = arrayInt
        
        for image in images {
            guard let imageData = image.recipeImageData else { return }
            imagesArray.append(imageData)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func pageChanged(_ sender: UIPageControl) {
        setOffsetX(pageNumber: sender.currentPage)
    }
    
    func setOffsetX(pageNumber: Int) {
        
        pageControl.currentPage = pageNumber
        let offsetX = contentView.bounds.width * CGFloat(pageNumber)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = offsetX
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func setImages() {
        
        // Set Page Count:
        pageControl.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count
        // Set Frame For ImageViews + Scroll View:
        for index in 0..<imagesArray.count {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.frame.size = contentView.bounds.size
            imageView.frame.origin.x = contentView.bounds.width * CGFloat(index)
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: imagesArray[index])
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true // Limits Frame Size
            
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
        
        // Set ScrollView Size:
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (contentView.bounds.width * CGFloat(imagesArray.count)), height: contentView.bounds.height)
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    
    // Set Page Number:
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
        delegate?.recipeImageViewSwiped(self, selectInt: pageControl.currentPage)
    }
```

The second cell contains a stackView with some labels to display data that the image shows. It accepts a lot of parameters and then sets the textColor and changes some labels. Nothing too exciting so I didn't include the code.

**DetailViewController:**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRowAt: ", indexPath)
    switch indexPath.section {
    case sectionImage:  // Section 0:
        guard
            let images = selectedGlaze?.glazeImage,
            let glazeImageSelected = selectedGlaze?.glazeImageSelected // This is a Double
            else { return returnDefaultCell() }
        
        let imageArray = images.allObjects as! [RecipeImage] // Takes NSSet of relational data and changes it into an Array to be passed into the image cell.
        let imageSelected = Int(glazeImageSelected) // Double Converted to Int
        
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = returnRecipeImageCell()
            return configureRecipeImageCell(cell: cell, for: indexPath, imagesArray: imageArray, imageSelected: imageSelected)
            
        case 1:
            let cell = returnAtmosphereCell()
            return configureAtmosphereCell(cell: cell, for: indexPath, imagesArray: imageArray, imageSelected: imageSelected)
            
        default: return returnDefaultCell()
        }
    }
}
```

**SwipedRecipeImageViewDelegate:**

```
func recipeImageViewSwiped(_ cell: RecipePhotoTableViewCell, selectInt: Int) {
    selectedGlaze?.glazeImageSelected = Double(selectInt)
    coreDataStack.saveContext()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // 
        self.tableView.beginUpdates() //
        let row1: IndexPath = [0,1] //
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [row1], with: .automatic) //
        self.tableView.endUpdates() //
    }
}
```

**The Issue:**
The issue I'm having is reloading the second cell to be updated with the correct information after the `recipeImageViewSwiped()` is called. Seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpyXs.jpg

This happens when the code inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block is active. When the block is comment out, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/be4e2.jpg - Which is what I'd expect. (Other than the cell at [0,1] isn't updated).

Specifically, when the tableView reloads row [0,1], cellForRowAt() only gets called on that row, [0,1]. But I'm not sure why the cell at [0,0], with the image, flicks back to the original image shown in the scrollView.

**Goal:**
My goal is to have the cell with the scrollView not flicker after being swiped on. But also to save the context, so that the object can save which image in the array is selected. And then to update/reload the second cell with the new information the image that's selected, so it can update it's labels correctly.

**EDIT:**

Removing the following in layoutSubviews() has this affect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vrdl.jpg - Which looks like it's mostly working. But still has a strange animation.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setImages()
    //        setOffsetX(pageNumber: selectedImageData)
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
This looks like its entirely an issue with setting up the cell's view. Along with layout Subviews.

**EDIT 3:**

I added a `Bool: hasSetLayout` and a switch inside of `layoutSubviews()` and it appears to be working as I want. - However if any one still has any information to help me understand this issue, I'd appreciate it.

```
var hasSetLayout = false

override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        switch hasSetLayout {
        case false: setImages(selectedPhoto: selectedImageData)
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a guess: the animation most probably happens because of this line of code: `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [row1], with: .automatic)`. Here, `.automatic` means that the table view is trying to choose the reload animaton for you. If you don't want the animation, replace `.automatic` with `.none` and see if it helped.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the reply. The issue is that the cell with the photos is at path `[0,0]`, So it shouldn't be reloaded. And I've confirmed that only the cell at [0,1] is truly reloaded when its called. - However, after that cell is reloaded, the photo cell at [0,0] is calling `layoutSubviews()` 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

try to reload row without animation :

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```